# Nifi equals condition doesnt match

Tags: conditional-statements, apache-nifi

Why the first condition always is skipping

```sql
${name:equals('xxx'):not():or('zzz'):not():or('aaa'):and(${number:equals(1)})}
```

Is

```sql
${name:equals('xxx')
```

skipped by NiFi

It doesn't matter which one condition is first always skipped by the processor

Any suggestions on what I can do ...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this expression

(check https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#or):

```sql
${name:equals('xxx'):not():or(${name:equals('xxx'):not()}):or(${name:equals('aaaa'):not()}):and(${number:equals(1)})}
```

Comment: not working 
now taking all flowilies not only first

Comment: @zolwik describe more your question with examples